# Sbt not resolving Scalatest on Intellij IDEA

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt, scalatest

I know there are already answered questions about this, but they didn't work for me, maybe because they are too old now.

So I'm creating a scala project on Intellij IDEA Ultimate (SDK 16.0.1). I compile it using sbt. I created a `MainTest` class in `src/test/scala` with the following content :

```scala
import org.scalatest.funsuite.AnyFunSuite

class MainTest extends AnyFunSuite {
  test("Example") {
    assert(1 == 1)
  }
}
```

On my `build.sbt` file I have :

```
name := "my-scala-project"

version := "0.1"

scalaVersion := "3.0.0-M2"

libraryDependencies += "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "1.4.RC2" % Test
```

I have also installed the library `org.scalatest:scalatest_2.11:3.1.0` from Maven from the File > Project Structure... > Project Settings > Libraries window

On the editor I can see that Intellij is unable to resolve the import on my test file as it is marked in red. When I run `sbt clean test`, I get this error message :

```
[error] -- [E006] Not Found Error: path\to\project\src\test\scala\MainTest.scala:4:2
[error] 4 |  test("Example") {
[error]   |  ^^^^
[error]   |  Not found: test
[error] one error found
[error] one error found
[error] (Test / compileIncremental) Compilation failed
```

Why isn't it working ? I thought I have done everything as expected. Ideally I would like to use the latest 3.2.9 version of Scalatest.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I combine all the help I got in the comment :

I had to write this in the `build.sbt` file :

```
name := "meteo-france-client"

version := "0.1"

scalaVersion := "3.0.0-M2"

libraryDependencies += "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "3.3.0-SNAP3" % Test
```

Then `sbt reload` and `sbt clean compile` and it works. However I now get this exceptions :

```
[info] compiling 1 Scala source to C:\Users\adrie\OneDrive\Documents\dev\meteo-france-client\target\scala-3.0.0-M2\test-classes ...
[error] ## Exception when compiling 1 sources to C:\Users\adrie\OneDrive\Documents\dev\meteo-france-client\target\scala-3.0.0-M2\test-classes
[error] java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/collection/immutable/List
[error] xsbt.CachedCompilerImpl.run(CachedCompilerImpl.java:65)
[error] xsbt.CompilerInterface.run(CompilerInterface.java:41)
[error] java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[error] java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78)
[error] java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[error] java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
[error] sbt.internal.inc.AnalyzingCompiler.invoke(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:329)
[error] sbt.internal.inc.AnalyzingCompiler.compile(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:112)
[error] sbt.internal.inc.MixedAnalyzingCompiler.$anonfun$compile$7(MixedAnalyzingCompiler.scala:192)
[error] scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
[error] sbt.internal.inc.MixedAnalyzingCompiler.timed(MixedAnalyzingCompiler.scala:247)
[error] sbt.internal.inc.MixedAnalyzingCompiler.$anonfun$compile$4(MixedAnalyzingCompiler.scala:182)
[error] sbt.internal.inc.MixedAnalyzingCompiler.$anonfun$compile$4$adapted(MixedAnalyzingCompiler.scala:163)
[error] sbt.internal.inc.JarUtils$.withPreviousJar(JarUtils.scala:239)
[error] sbt.internal.inc.MixedAnalyzingCompiler.compileScala$1(MixedAnalyzingCompiler.scala:163)
[error] sbt.internal.inc.MixedAnalyzingCompiler.compile(MixedAnalyzingCompiler.scala:210)
[error] sbt.internal.inc.IncrementalCompilerImpl.$anonfun$compileInternal$1(IncrementalCompilerImpl.scala:528)
[error] sbt.internal.inc.IncrementalCompilerImpl.$anonfun$compileInternal$1$adapted(IncrementalCompilerImpl.scala:528)
[error] sbt.internal.inc.Incremental$.$anonfun$apply$5(Incremental.scala:175)
[error] sbt.internal.inc.Incremental$.$anonfun$apply$5$adapted(Incremental.scala:173)
[error] sbt.internal.inc.Incremental$$anon$2.run(Incremental.scala:459)
[error] sbt.internal.inc.IncrementalCommon$CycleState.next(IncrementalCommon.scala:116)
[error] sbt.internal.inc.IncrementalCommon$$anon$1.next(IncrementalCommon.scala:56)
[error] sbt.internal.inc.IncrementalCommon$$anon$1.next(IncrementalCommon.scala:52)
[error] sbt.internal.inc.IncrementalCommon.cycle(IncrementalCommon.scala:263)
[error] sbt.internal.inc.Incremental$.$anonfun$incrementalCompile$8(Incremental.scala:414)
[error] sbt.internal.inc.Incremental$.withClassfileManager(Incremental.scala:501)
[error] sbt.internal.inc.Incremental$.incrementalCompile(Incremental.scala:401)
[error] sbt.internal.inc.Incremental$.apply(Incremental.scala:167)
[error] sbt.internal.inc.IncrementalCompilerImpl.compileInternal(IncrementalCompilerImpl.scala:528)
[error] sbt.internal.inc.IncrementalCompilerImpl.$anonfun$compileIncrementally$1(IncrementalCompilerImpl.scala:482)
[error] sbt.internal.inc.IncrementalCompilerImpl.handleCompilationError(IncrementalCompilerImpl.scala:332)
[error] sbt.internal.inc.IncrementalCompilerImpl.compileIncrementally(IncrementalCompilerImpl.scala:420)
[error] sbt.internal.inc.IncrementalCompilerImpl.compile(IncrementalCompilerImpl.scala:137)
[error] sbt.Defaults$.compileIncrementalTaskImpl(Defaults.scala:2357)
[error] sbt.Defaults$.$anonfun$compileIncrementalTask$2(Defaults.scala:2314)
[error] sbt.internal.io.Retry$.apply(Retry.scala:46)
[error] sbt.internal.io.Retry$.apply(Retry.scala:28)
[error] sbt.internal.io.Retry$.apply(Retry.scala:23)
[error] sbt.internal.server.BspCompileTask$.compute(BspCompileTask.scala:31)
[error] sbt.Defaults$.$anonfun$compileIncrementalTask$1(Defaults.scala:2310)
[error] scala.Function1.$anonfun$compose$1(Function1.scala:49)
[error] sbt.internal.util.$tilde$greater.$anonfun$$u2219$1(TypeFunctions.scala:62)
[error] sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(Transform.scala:68)
[error] sbt.Execute.$anonfun$submit$2(Execute.scala:282)
[error] sbt.internal.util.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:23)
[error] sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:291)
[error] sbt.Execute.$anonfun$submit$1(Execute.scala:282)
[error] sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4.$anonfun$submitValid$1(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:265)
[error] sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:64)
[error] java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
[error] java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
[error] java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
[error] java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
[error] java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630)
[error] java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:831)
[error]
[error] stack trace is suppressed; run 'last Test / compileIncremental' for the full output
[error] (Test / compileIncremental) java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/collection/immutable/List
[error] Total time: 0 s, completed 26 nov. 2021, 13:33:34
```

I'll make another post about it : [Sbt unable to find List class definition on Scala 3.0.0-M2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70124733/sbt-unable-to-find-list-class-definition-on-scala-3-0-0-m2)

Thanks for all who have helped me here

Answer (score 1):

You need to do two things to fix your code:

1. Update `build.sbt` to use the correct dependency; and
2. Extend your test class with the necessary trait.

For 1:

Import the Scalatest library with the following:

```
libraryDependencies += "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "3.2.10" % Test
```

When you use `_2.11` in the current configuration you're asking SBT to find you version of scalatest for Scala 2.11, but you're using Scala 3.1.0. The `%%` is a helper to pull in the correct version of Scalatest for your Scala version.

For 2:

Change your file [as per the documention](https://www.scalatest.org/scaladoc/3.1.2/org/scalatest/funsuite/AnyFunSuite.html) to:

```
class MainTest extends AnyFunSuite {
  test("Example") {
    assert(1 == 1)
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I fixed the build.sbt file but when trying to install scalatest from Maven, it only finds version up to 1.5 and I don't understant what is it related to. It's surely not the scala version (3.0.1) nor the scalatest one (3.2.10). Thanks

Comment: When you say 'it only finds version up to 1.5' what you do you mean? Once you add the `libraryDependency` to your `build.sbt` file run `sbt reload` in a shell to update the dependency automatically. You should see the jar in your managed resources directory.

Comment: I mean I get this error when running `sbt clean test` after reloading :
`[warn]  Note: Unresolved dependencies path:
[error] stack trace is suppressed; run 'last update' for the full output
[error] (update) sbt.librarymanagement.ResolveException: Error downloading org.scalatest:scalatest_3.0.0-M2:1.4.RC2
[error]   Not found
[error]   Not found
[error]   not found: C:\Users\adrie\.ivy2\localorg.scalatest\scalatest_3.0.0-M2\1.4.RC2\ivys\ivy.xml
[error]   not found: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scalatest/scalatest_3.0.0-M2/1.4.RC2/scalatest_3.0.0-M2-1.4.RC2.pom`

Comment: It's not clear why the maven directory path includes `1.4.RC2`. Can you please update your original question with your full `build.sbt` as it currently looks?

Comment: It includes 1.4.RC2 as this is the latest available version I can find on Maven. I updated the question as desired.

Comment: Looking at Maven for Scalatest artifacts compiled for Scala `3.0.0-M2` (https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scalatest/scalatest_3.0.0-M2/) there are two versions available, `3.2.3` or `3.3.0-SNAP3`. Given your current `build.sbt` file if you change `libraryDependencies += "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "1.4.RC2" % Test` to `libraryDependencies += "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "3.3.0-SNAP3" % Test` then run `sbt clean compile` it should work.

Comment: Nope, I still get `not found: C:\Users\adrie\.ivy2\localorg.scalatest\scalatest_3.0.0-M2\1.4.RC2\ivys\ivy.xml` and `not found: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scalatest/scalatest_3.0.0-M2/1.4.RC2/scalatest_3.0.0-M2-1.4.RC2.pom`. I think I need to manually install it on Intellij, but if I do so, he only proposes up to 1.4.RC2 (look at this screenshot please : https://i.ibb.co/7KL3d5t/Capture-d-cran-2021-11-26-112322.png).

Or maybe I should install it manually on my computer, but if so, will it compile on a CI ?

Comment: The reason we use tools like SBT and Maven is so as not to manually install dependencies. I'd suggest at this point invalidating your Intellij caches and restarting. Johny T Koshy and can both download the dependency using only the configuration file and SBT.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you have to change the `scalaVersion` to `3.0.0`, which is the latest supported.

As far as dependencies are concerned, as Jarrod has mentioned, you could either use

```
"org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "3.2.10" % Test
```

When using `groupID %% artifactID % revision` you are telling sbt to fetch the artifactID suited for the scala version you have provided, in this case, `3.0.0-M2`.

You can also use `groupID % artifactID % revision`. Like in your question, if `scalatest_2.11` is the artifactID, it means `scalatest` for scala version `2.11.x` will be downloaded.

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't solve my problem. I installed the Maven library `org.scalatest:scalatest:1.3`. I don't know why Maven can't find sooner versions of it (I updated the sbt to use 1.3 when downloading the 1.3 library from intellij libraries utility)

Comment: It's not clear what you have done. Can you tell the current `scalaVersion` and `libraryDependencies` from your `build.sbt` file?

Comment: As you suggested I put 3.0.0-M2 for scala version (is it stable ?) and `org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "1.4.RC2" % Test` for scalatest dependency in the sbt file (there's no newer one in Maven than 1.4.RC2 ‍♂️)

Comment: `1.4.RC2` don't have a compatible build for `scala 3.0.0-M2`.  You have to use version `3.3.0-SNAP3` for `scalatest`. This setup works in my local environment with sbt `1.5.5` and java 11.

Comment: Well maybe for you but Maven does not find scalatest 3.3.0-SNAP3 for me. It just stops at 1.4 : https://i.ibb.co/7KL3d5t/Capture-d-cran-2021-11-26-112322.png

Comment: You don't have to manually add scalatest using `Project Settings` -> `Libraries` of Intellij. Instead use, `build.sbt`: add `scalaVersion`, `libraryDependencies` and reload the project. Reloading can be done using `sbt reload` from command line or there will be a refresh icon on the top right corner of Intellij editor after you update `build.sbt`. It could be that the newer versions of scalatest are not added in Intellij (I don't know). Also, it would help you to go through a tutorial on how to setup a scala project using sbt.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239603/discussion-between-johny-t-koshy-and-adrien-merat).

Comment: @AdrienMerat, Please see the updated answer. The milestone version of scala was causing the error you mentioned in chat. I have updated that. Added the same in chat too for reference.